# Dynamics ax 4.0, opening form without applying filter on current record

Tags: axapta

I have form with VendTable grid for example, which has CustAccount field.

I want to place button, click on which will open CustTable form where all customers are visible.

If I just put CustTable menuitem, then clicking on it will open CustTable form, but in this form only one record is displayed - one that has the same AccountNum as in vendTable.CustAccount.

How to open whole custTable? Is there better solution than create button, and then use ClassFactory::FormRunOnClient to display form?

PS. I need button, so RMB->"Go to the Main Table Form" doesn't count.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the `VendTable` record is applied as an argument to the `CustTable` form, which then creates a dynalink. The solution is to avoid the argument.

Override the `clicked` method in the `CustTable` display menu item like this:

```
void clicked()
{
    this.menufunction().run(new Args(element));
}
```

This calls the `CustTable` form with the caller object only and without the record argument.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a fairly old question but if someone comes here looking for the answer, just call method `clearDynalinks()` on the object QueryBuildDataSource.

For example, you have created a Form and it is automatically filtering your Datasource because of the Dynalinks that Dynamics creates automatically, you solve it by putting the following code inside the `init()` method, on your form Datasource:

```
QueryBuildDatasource qbds;
;


qbds = this.query().dataSourceTable(tablenum(MyTableName));
qbds.clearDynalinks();

// Next line is optional, it clears initial ranges
qbds.clearRanges();

// if you need to add any ranges you can do it right after you clear the initial dynalinks / ranges
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options, you can either create a button and override its clicked() method, or
use a MenuItemButton and assign an Action MenuItem to it.

Using MenuItems is a best practice, because it allows you to use the AX security & configuration framework. You can associate a class to the MenuItem and in the class' main() method you can run the FormRunOnClient() stuff as needed.